# How to restrict SQL Server Function from rounding Money returned value

Tags: sql, sql-server, function

I made a function to get the Conversion Rate with return money value, but why does the sql server do rounding on the data output.

I made a scalar function on SQL Server with return output money

```
CREATE FUNCTION CurrencyRate(
-- Add the parameters for the function here
@FromCurr  CHAR(3), 
@ToCurr    CHAR(3), 
@Date_Tran DATE)
RETURNS MONEY
AS
     BEGIN
         -- Declare the return variable here
         DECLARE @CurrencyRate MONEY;

         -- the T-SQL statements to compute the return value here
         SELECT @CurrencyRate = CAST(tc.scale AS MONEY)
         FROM dbo.TCurrencyConverter tc
         WHERE @Date_Tran BETWEEN tc.start_date AND tc.end_date
               AND tc.currency_id_1 = @FromCurr
               AND tc.currency_id_2 = @ToCurr;

         -- Return the result of the function
         RETURN @CurrencyRate;
     END;
GO
```

I expect the output is `0.000070550000000`, but the actual output is `0.0001`.

Comment: Doesn't money data type have 4 decimals?

Comment: @jarlh - [indeed it does](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/money-and-smallmoney-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) "The money and smallmoney data types are accurate to a ten-thousandth of the monetary units that they represent."

Comment: don't use `money` data type for conversion rate. Depending on your requirement on number of decimal places, use `decimal` or `numeric` example :  `declare @CurrencyRate 
 decimal(18,8)`

Answer (score 1):

This is the max size of money datatype in `sqlserver` is

```
92233720368547.9999
```

you can use numeric() as return type.

```
cast('0.000070550000000' as numeric(18,18))
```

Comment: Will have no effect - the return type is defined as MONEY.

Comment: @Smor . . . I think the point is that you want to return `numeric`/`decimal`, not `money`.